# I have the REST API on 11.2 working but some calls I cant see

Tags: deepsecurity

Hi guys I have the REST API on 11.2 working fine and can update the computers etc

But I cant see a couple of calls in the API docs or maybe they are not added yet

1) In the Web-interface you can send a deactivate  action but I can'e see an API call for that. I can get around that if needed by using Ansible as I used that to provision the Agent

2) How do you view the events with the API ? that one I cant see at all I want to show any to my customers on our web portal

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The API does not provide access to Agent actions or events. However:

- The legacy SOAP API can activate/deactivate agents:
  https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/transition-from-the-soap-api
- The legacy RESt API provides access to events:
  https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_2/use-the-previous-rest-api

I create content for that site BTW...thanks for your question  :)